# Почему выдает данную ошибку Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции в VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

Не получается установить библиотеки через pip в visual studio code
выдает такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Начать стоит с логичного вопроса — а почему вы решили, что команда pip вообще должна быть? Что вы для этого предприняли? Python вообще устанавливали? Установку pip не отключали? В PATH добавляли?

Comment: В том то и дело что я могу смело на все 3 вопроса ДА

Comment: @vlad, но ошибка буквально означает, что в PATH путь к pip не прописан. Так что прописывайте, и все заработает.